# Deploy Camel-Restlet Endpoint into Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat7, apache-camel, restlet

I have a requirement to deploy my Camel Restlet endpoint into Tomcat and run it from there. The example provided in the Apache Camel Distribution (camel-example-restlet-jdbc) does not work when deployed into Tomcat. Any idea on how we can correct this?
I am using Camel 2.11.1 and camel-restlet 2.7.1. Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <groupId>com.walmart.asda</groupId>
  <artifactId>Camel_Servlet_Web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Restlet</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>An example showing how to create REST API with Camel Restlet and JDBC components</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:camel-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
            <param-value>RestletComponent</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the camel-context.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
                           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

   <!--  <import resource="java-dsl.xml" /> -->

    <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="restlet:/users/{userId}?restletMethods=GET" />
            <transform>
                <simple>Hello ${header.userId} how are you?</simple>
            </transform>
        </route>
    </camel:camelContext>

    <bean id="RestletComponent" class="org.restlet.Component" />

    <bean id="RestletComponentService" class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <ref bean="RestletComponent" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>   

</beans>
```

When I package and deploy this application into Tomcat 7.0.53, and hit the following URL `http://localhost:8081/Restlet/rs/users/123`, here is the exception I get:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet RestletServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
    org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet.getWebApplicationContext(SpringServerServlet.java:140)
    org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet.createComponent(SpringServerServlet.java:116)
    org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.getComponent(ServerServlet.java:843)
    org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.init(ServerServlet.java:961)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

When you using camel-restlet, you should chose the same version of camel-core.
Please change the camel-restlet version to 2.11.1.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution - it was an issue with the dependency...tried a dependency:tree and found that camel-restlet 2.11.1 uses org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:jar:2.0.15. So the version of the org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.spring:jar should also be 2.0.15 - I was using version 2.2.1. Once I changed the version and deployed into Tomcat, it worked without any issues. Here is the updated POM that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <groupId>com.walmart.asda</groupId>
  <artifactId>Camel_Servlet_Web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Restlet</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```